# w3wp.exe taking entire CPU

Tags: .net, iis

We have three websites hosted in our IIS, each one has a seperate App Pool associated with it. But I see the CPU spikes to 100 % when I request for a page the w3wp process takes 100% of CPU .
 Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: This question probably belongs on ServerFault. Not Stackoverflow.

Comment: @The.Anti.9: I don't really agree, it's potentially more of a debugging question, than a server admin question

Answer (score 2):

Get a profiler, attach it to the w3wp process and figure out where the CPU is spending time. Then fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take the memory dump and use windbg to analyze what is taking up all the cpu power.
Most likely you're doing something wrong in your code that takes up all the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

First use `iisapp.vbs` from a command prompt (installed by default, it should be on the PATH), to figure out what website is causing the problem. It lists PID - AppPool Name.

Install [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx)

Then using a command prompt execute `adplus.vbs -p PID -hang` to create a memorydump.

Check out the [WinDbg Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx) and [Tess's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) to figure out how to use windbg to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a crappy server CPU.

Does it only have a single logical CPU? If so, upgrade it to at least a dual core of sorts.

The new Core i7's would be a good and relatively cheap option.